# ltconfig not found

Tags: rhel, software-installation, compiling

I am using RHEL 7.3 workstation version. I am trying to install Xbae -4.8.4 and I am using the script supplied by the developer to install it. However, when I try to install it, I get the following error.

```
updating cache ./config.cache
loading cache ./config.cache within ltconfig
ltconfig: you must specify a host type if you use `--no-verify'
Try `ltconfig --help' for more information.
configure: error: libtool configure failed
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found
```

Does anybody know what is happening? Please suggest some methods to resolve this problem.

Comment: what were the commands that you ran?

Comment: Please post the full command of the installation. Probably you are trying to install this software from sources, right? So, post the `./configure` you used to provide your software parameters at compilation time...

Comment: Here is the configure file

Comment: Oops I thought I could upload the config file but no. How do I post the configure file that is 2500 lines long?